# XSLT можно ли обращаться без пространства имен?

Tags: xml, xslt

есть XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="1.xslt" ?>
<ns1:Элемент1 xmlns:ns1="пространство1" >
  <ns2:элемент2 xmlns:ns2="пространство2">
    <ns3:элемент3 xmlns:ns3="пространство3">
      привет
    </ns3:элемент3>
  </ns2:элемент2>
</ns1:Элемент1 >
```

есть шаблон XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns1="пространство1"
  xmlns:ns2="пространство2"
  xmlns:ns3="пространство3"
  >
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="ns1:Элемент1">
    <b>ТЕКСТ =</b>
    <xsl:value-of select="./ns2:элемент2/ns3:элемент3"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

но стоит изменить у XML пространство имен, шаблон уже не видит этих тегов... надо снова прописать новые пространства в шаблоне...
как можно заставить XSLT как-то игнорить пространство имен, а просто обращаться по именам?

не так

```
./ns2:элемент2/ns3:элемент3
```

а так

```
./элемент2/элемент3
```

Comment: Вам же предлагали уже `local-name()` и предварительную трансформацию для удаления неймспейсов.

Answer (score 1):

Убрать в xml файле все упоминания о пространствах имен.

Comment: Это как при переломе ноги советовать отрубить её. Вопрошающему надо именно с пространствами имён. Вполне возможно, что он вообще получает XML-файлы со стороны, а потому не может повлиять на их схему.

Comment: в том и проблема, когда работаешь с xml, что придется или рубить или использовать. В один проход зачастую мало что удается сделать, и приходится иногда по 3-5 шагов делать, в том числе прогонять через Perl как текст.

Comment: Да, мне нужно, чтобы XML не трагался, как то можно в шаблоне отключить это? чтобы игнорил он эти ns ???

Comment: Как и говорили выше, то через конструкции типа: `/path/to/*[local-name() = 'элемент1']` других вариантов нет, если ns не вырезать.

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг ^^^